# Adding an administrator to a Facebook page using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do I add an administrator to a Facebook page using the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you have to use the [Facebook Developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).